# how to check if 2 strings contain equal characters?

Tags: c++

im trying to make a function that will take two strings from user and check if they contain equal characters. For example test and set , both these strings contain the letter t and s so the output should be `true`. I started a few weeks ago so im having some trouble with executing the code correctly.  Can someone please explain what im doing wrong?  thanks everyone

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool equal(char first, char second);

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string first;

  string second;

  bool equal;
  int se;
  cout << "enter a string " << endl;
  getline(cin, first);
  cout << "enter another string " << endl;
  getline(cin, second);
  equal(first ,second);

  if (equal) {
    cout << "strings are equal" << endl;
  } else if (!equal) {
    cout << "strings not " << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

bool equal(string first, string second) {
  for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = j + 1; i < second.length(); i++) {
      if (i == j)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `test == sett` need to be true?

Comment: ,  they both contain t and s so the program should output that strings contain similar letters.

Comment: Could you clarify what "contain equal characters" means to you?

Comment: for example test and set , both these strings contain the letter t and s so the output should be true

Comment: `bool equal(char first, char second);`, `bool equal`, `bool equal(string first, string second)` (and `std::equal` thanks to `using namespace std;`)...

Comment: in your check function you compare i and j which are the indexes (numbers) of the loops. You need to get the characters in the string.

Comment: And your loop with returns immediately...

Comment: Since you are already using `std::string` why not use [`find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of)?

Comment: thanks for your tips but  the assignment doesnt allow me to use any of the built in string functions exept for str.length()

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
bool contain_same_letters(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
    return std::set<char>(lhs.begin(), lhs.end())
        == std::set<char>(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
}
```

Comment: From the comments, OP wants to see if there's a non-empty set intersection.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Indeed, it is not clear what OP wants, `"set"` and `"test"` works for both interpretation, but OP just justifies it on `'s'` and `'t'` (ignoring `'e'`).

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop of `equal()` is wrong, it should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < second.size(); j++)
    if (first[i] == second[j])
```

instead of

```
for (int j = j + 1; i < second.length(); i++) {
    if (i == j)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can guess at the error message (don't make us, though!). You declared `bool equal(char first, char second);` but defined `bool equal(string first, string second)`. Hence, when you try to call it, the compiler complains about an incorrect argument type.

Your next problem will be at runtime, because your implementation of `equal` isn't working right. But this is an algorithm problem; you should think about how it should work. You can't return when there's one match, but you *can* return when there's one mis-match.

There is also a smart trick by using the functions from `<algorithm>` but I won't give that away. One hint, though: it's hard to compare "test" and "set" because the letters are in a different order.

Comment: thanks for your tips ! if i use bool equal ( string first, string second ) in the parameters it tells me that string is undeclared indentifier.. also it give s me error when i try to declare the function.

Comment: @vladimrminchenko: Do you know what `using namespace std` does? Now look where you put that.

Comment: yeah my bad. but it is still giving me an error when i try to call the function , also its saying type name is not allowed.

Comment: @vladimrminchenko: As you're still learning, look a bit harder. This too is almost certainly a silly mistake just like the problem with `using namespace std;`. You'll need to learn how to find such small mistakes, because you will keep encountering them (if only due to typo's - I still slip in the occasional : instead of a ; when I miss the sihft key)

Comment: not seeing it.. maybe i called the function in the wrong place?